# Is there a way to bypass node-fetch res.text() to get a raw response body?

Tags: node.js

I'm having node-fetch issues.  An API that I can access perfectly fine in POSTMAN throws the same error using node-fetch and I cannot get it to spit out a response body.  I know there must be one and I have theories why it's likely improperly formatted.

Here is my code.

```
fetch(`apiUrl`, options)
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        return res.text();
        })
    .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        });
```

This code never prints a response body event after calling res.text().  My question is there another way to get to the RAW response body other than call .text() so that I can see if the API is responding.  It's responding with a status:200 and I'm fairly certain there is a body because when I cURL from PHP and request from POSTMAN I get the expected response body.

The errors is always:

FetchError: invalid response body at: apiUrl reason: unexpected end of file

Comment: try json instead of text

Comment: it throws the same error.  Invalid response body unexpected end of file

Comment: check if the response you get in postman is a valid json ?, also try to `await res.text()`

Comment: The response I get from postman is a valid JSON.  At least when I throw it into a .json file and load it into a variable node parses it properly into an object.  The question still remains.  Why can't I get fetch to spit out a raw body.  Why is it so hard to get that?

Answer (score 1):

So I'm going to post an answer to this question because it deserves an answer and other folks might run into this eventually.  Basically you need to be careful the version of "fetch" packaged with Express isn't exactly the same as node-fetch.  They handle errors differently.  In this instance my issue was a blank response in which case no body to actually stream.  express fetch throw the error that I described above however node-fetch thrown an intelligible error and returns a response body when res.text() is called the response body is just blank.  In my application I made sure that I'm always using node-fetch and it's better.  Not perfect but avoid using the express fetch dependency if possible.

Also coincidentally the reason for the intermittent blank response body that I was getting was due to a lack of a Connection header.  Adding "Connection: keep-alive" to all of my requests fixed the issue with the API not completing it's answer.

So this could be a secondary answer for both of these is add a keep-alive to all of your API requests as a best practice unless there is a reason for you not to do that to avoid blank response bodies on a 200 response.